# reusing HTML in two places within SAME view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a chunk of HTML (it's a menu) which is in two places in a view's HTML.

How to reuse it in both places?

I know I could put the HTML in a separate `.cshtml` and then use `@Html.Partial("Menu")` but since it's needed only within same view, it seems overkill to have a separate file.

Is there another way?

Comment: `@Html.Partial("Menu")` sounds like the correct way to handle this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Using a partial view to avoid code repetition, even within the same view, is better than having to duplicate it. In release mode the locations of those views are cached and there will be no performance impact of having to include them multiple times in your main view.

Comment: Thanks. But I still think it's overkill to have a separate file for this scenario. I have at least 2 views in this scenario. This means I need to create 2 additional files.

Comment: OK, then why are you asking here if you think that it is an overkill?

Comment: Because I was thinking there is another way, for this particular scenario where you are NOT sharing the HTML across different views.

Comment: The way to reuse markup in ASP.NET MVC is either through partial views or custom HTML helpers.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with `@helper` syntax:

```
@MyMenu()

<!-- another place on same page -->
@MyMenu()

<!-- On same page -->
@helper MyMenu
{
   <!-- Shared HTML here -->
}
```

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor

I'm not sure if there's any cons in using `@helper` but it does the job in this scenario where the HTML doesn't need to be shared across pages, only within same page.